# DataTemplate for DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

The way I see a DataTemplate is that it is something you can pass to a control that says "Display my stuff like so". You can use the template on a single control (eg ContentControl) or some sort of list control (eg ListBox). What I've always thought was missing was a way to define a template that tells a multicolumn control such as the DataGrid a way to display something. Say I want to pass a list of staff to the DataGrid and tell it to show the staff id in the first column, name in the second column etc. I can pass a template for each column but that gets a bit messy. I would like to define a single template that describes how to display an object in a multi column control.

To solve this problem I created my own very rough classes which I call DataGridTemplate and DataGridTemplateColumnTemplate. This works and I have used it in a couple of places in my app but I'm fairly certain this isn't the best way to do it. It's just a class, it doesn't inherit from DataTemplate and if I need to set properties on the grid or columns of the grid then I need to duplicate every one of those properties. Anyway, my question is, is there a better way to do this?

```
[System.Windows.Markup.ContentProperty("Columns")]
public class DataGridTemplate
{        
    public List<DataGridTemplateColumnTemplate> Columns { get; set; }

    public Style Style { get; set; }

    public DataGridTemplate()
    {
        Columns = new List<DataGridTemplateColumnTemplate>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataGridTemplateColumn> CreateColumns()
    {
        return Columns.Select(c => c.CreateColumn());
    }

    public void ApplyToGrid(DataGrid grid)
    {
        if(Style != null) grid.Style = Style;
        grid.Columns.Clear();
        CreateColumns().AddAllTo(grid.Columns);
    }
}

public class DataGridTemplateColumnTemplate
{
    public object Header { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate CellTemplate { get; set; }
    public double MinWidth { get; set; }
    public double MaxWidth { get; set; }

    public DataGridTemplateColumnTemplate()
    {
        MinWidth = 20.0;
        MaxWidth = double.PositiveInfinity;
    }

    public DataGridTemplateColumn CreateColumn()
    {
        var col = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        col.Header = Header;
        col.CellTemplate = CellTemplate;
        col.MinWidth = MinWidth;
        col.MaxWidth = MaxWidth;
        return col;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a DataTemplateSelector?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want a single template that will define the layout for the entire grid, ie the template will define multiple columns. A template selector won't help with this